# Excel line chart to populate info up until TODAY()?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My example chart below tracks 'planned vs actual' dates. Is there a solution for 'Actual' data to only populate up until the current date (and not extend through the entire x-axis)?

[image]

Comment: Does [this thread on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/1042023/529100) help?  Or [this one](https://superuser.com/q/841799/529100)? What have you tried?

Comment: @BruceWayne - thanks, I used info from your first link to add a Boolean column and then utilized the NA() function instead of a null value :)